# Prepopulate Url Parameters on a visualforcepage that is in console app

Tags: visualforce, console, custom-url

I am trying to prepopulate my url parameters on the visualforce page that is in the console application

**This is the url i am trying to use**

https://my.salesforce.com/console?tsid=consoleappid&Lastname=Jackson&phone=xxxxxxxx

**Apex code:**

```
urllastname = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Lastname');
urlphonenumber = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('phone');
```

**Visualforce Page**

```
<apex:inputText styleClass="form-control" value="{!urlphonenumber}" /> 
<apex:inputText styleClass="form-control" value="{!urllastname}" />
```

When i am trying to use this URL it works fine

https://my.salesforce.com/apex/myvisualforcepage?Lastname=Jackson&phone=xxxxxx

But i want it to prepopulate in Console App.

Anyhelp would be appreciated!

Comment: You need to take the URL string and perform a logic for parsing